# Can I declare more than one converter? WP8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, converters

I am using BooleanToVisibilityConvertor for manipulating visibility of TextBlock in a ListBox DataTemplate.

Here is my XAML code:

```
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Converters:BooleanToVisibilityConvertor x:Key="booleanToVisibilityConvertor"/>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Padding="0,0,7,0" Visibility="{Binding AverageConsumption, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConvertor}}"> 
     <Run Text="{Binding AverageConsumption}"/>
     <Run Text="l./100 km."/>
    </TextBlock>
```

And the code behind:

```
public class BooleanToVisibilityConvertor : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
                {
                    return Visibility.Visible;
                }

            }
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This is working correct, but i need one more (reversed) convertor for another TextBlock placed on the same position (Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right")
with static Text="Partial Refueling" so when {Binding AverageConsumption} is not null or empty first TextBlock will be vissible and second will be collapsed and vice versa. Something like this:

```
    class BooleanToVisibilityConvertorReversed : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
                {
                    return Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
            }
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I have tried to declare another convertor in XAML:

```
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Converters:BooleanToVisibilityConvertor x:Key="booleanToVisibilityConvertor"/>
    <Converters:BooleanToVisibilityConvertorReversed x:Key="booleanToVisibilityConvertorReversed"/>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

But got an exception on InitializeComponent():
'A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll'
How can i solve this?

Comment: Why do you think that this line is a culprit?

Comment: I think the reason is here:     <Converters:BooleanToVisibilityConvertorReversed x:Key="booleanToVisibilityConvertorReversed"/> and it just can't Initialize the page. I have removed the other converter and tried only with this one, but still have the same exception.

Comment: And if you remove it the error will be gone? Maybe some hidden symbol is there? Try to type it anew with the IntelliSense help

Comment: I judt did, but it is still the same. I can Build it, but can't Initialize the page. Actually can i use more then one converter like this?

Comment: Sure you can. It is just another resource. Nothing special

Comment: I have no idea what's going on then. When i remove the one which is working and add a new one like this:    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <Converters:VisibilityConvertor x:Key="visibilityConvertor"/>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources> still have the same problem. Maybe 'BooleanToVisibilityConvertor 'is something like reserved class and the name can't be different?

Comment: It is not giving me an exception even if i declare BooleanToVisibilityConvertor twice with different keys, but not and when i delcare BooleanToVisibilityConvertorReversed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I've found what is your problem. Your `BooleanToVisibilityConvertorReversed` class is not public. Make it public and your issues should be gone.

Comment: We almost crossed our answers haha. I just found the same and it is working now. Thank you anyway! You were first, so i will mark you answer :)